# Creating a virtual directory in apache on osx

Tags: macos, apache

I am trying to create a virtual directory in apache on a mac. I have my localhost ip 127.0.0.1 renamed to abctest.dev using a virtual host. I would like to create a mapping to an existing directory something like this:

sites/mywebsite/project, I want to be able to create an alias say 'projectone' for the project and just use something like abctest.dev/projectone while accessing it using the url. Can any one please provide any ideas on how to achieve this. I have already tried doing this mentioned in here but with no luck. [Tried this](http://w3shaman.com/article/creating-virtual-directory-apache). Any ideas are appreciated. thanks

```
<IfModule alias_module>

Alias /projectone /sites/myproject/project

<Directory "/sites/myproject/project">
Options None
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: What are the errors? Check your log files.

Comment: I am new to apache and OSX, where do I check the log files?

Comment: Can you provide the httpd.conf section of the file that you modified.

Comment: You might have done something link [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html#outside) from the Apache docs.

Comment: Updated the quesiton

Comment: Copy the line that has "LoadModule alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_alias.so"